# MongoDB is slower than SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the same data of around 30 million record saved in a SQL Server table and a MongoDB collection. A sample record is shown below, I have set up the same indexes as well. Below are the queries to return the same data, one in SQL the other in mongo. The SQL query takes 2 seconds to compute and return, mongo on the other hand takes 50. Any ideas why mongo so much slower than SQL??

SQL

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT IP) AS Count,
    DATEPART(dy, datetime)
FROM 
    collection
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(dy, datetime)
```

MONGO

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$group:{ "_id": { $dayOfYear:"$datetime" }, IP: { $addToSet: "$IP"} }},{$unwind:"$IP"},{$group:{ _id: "$_id", count: { $sum:1} }}])
```

Sample Document, there are around 30 million of exact same data in both

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("57968ebc7391bb1f7c2f4801"),
  "IP" : "127.0.0.1",
  "userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+LCTE;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko",
  "Country" : null,
  "datetime" : ISODate("2016-07-25T16:50:18-05:00"),
  "proxy" : null,
  "url" : "/records/archives/archivesdb/deathcertificates/",
  "HTTPStatus" : "302",
  "HTTPResponseTime" : "218"
}
```

**EDIT**: added the explanation of both queries

MONGO

```
{
    "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
    "stages" : [
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {

                },
                "fields" : {
                    "IP" : 1,
                    "datetime" : 1,
                    "_id" : 0
                },
                "queryPlanner" : {
                    "plannerVersion" : 1,
                    "namespace" : "IISLogs.pubprdweb01",
                    "indexFilterSet" : false,
                    "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$and" : [ ]
                    },
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "filter" : {
                            "$and" : [ ]
                        },
                        "direction" : "forward"
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : {
                    "$dayOfYear" : [
                        "$datetime"
                    ]
                },
                "IP" : {
                    "$addToSet" : "$IP"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$unwind" : {
                "path" : "$IP"
            }
        },
        {
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : "$_id",
                "count" : {
                    "$sum" : {
                        "$const" : 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

SQL Server I don't have the permissions on it since I'm not a DBA or anything but it works fast enough that I'm not too concerned about its execution plan, the troublesome thing to me is that the mongo is using FETCH

Comment: Could you post the execution plans for both mysql and mongo?

Comment: AFAIK, MongoDB is NoSQL and those database engines are designed for BigData and Non-Relational database. That's might be the result. I'm interested to know what is the answer too :)

Comment: I have updated the question to include the execution plan for mongo, I agree if Mongo is taking this long to do something that SQL took no time on there must obviously be something configured wrong because like you said it is designed to handle big data more over SQL

Comment: MongoDB isn't very good at aggregation, so this isn't really surprising.

Comment: Please provide the MongoDB version and the listing of indexes for your collection.

Comment: Mongo version is 3.2.7, indexes for both are datetime:-1 IP:1, for mongo this is a compound index for SQL it is a non-clustered index

Answer (score 3):

The MongoDB version is slow because `$group` [can't use an index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#aggregation-pipeline-operators-and-performance) (as evidenced by the `"COLLSCAN"` in the query plan), so all 30 million docs must be read into memory and run through the pipeline.

This type of real-time query (computing summary data from all docs) is simply not a good fit for MongoDB. It would be better to periodically run your `aggregate` with an [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out) stage (or use a map-reduce) to generate the summary data from the main collection and then query the resulting summary collection instead.

Comment: So that's the fault of mongo then? Since it can't use an index on the group? But still sql only took a couple of seconds and also had to scan the entire table so what's the point of trying to use the mongo?

Comment: It does not necessarily have to be a map reduce. Adding a simple `$out` stage might well serve the same purpose better.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Right, that's what I meant by "(or aggregate)". I'll clarify.